# PHP Greatly speed up execution time of my script

Tags: php, arrays

I have a heavy script that we run plenty. Below is the algorithm used:

1. Load 4500 rows from database and store them as an array. (A)
2. Load 600000 rows from database and store them as an array. (B)
3. For each element in (A) looks for a match in (B).
4. go to next element in (A)

So the maximum amount of iteration of this script are 4500 * 60 000 which is 270,000,000 so you understand that this can be a bit sweaty for PHP.

Can I make this process more efficient somehow? 
Reading the rows from a database is not really an issue it is the array iterations that bring heavy costs.

It does work pretty fast but one factor (60000) will increase greatly in the years to come.

So any ideas?

Comment: Provide us your queries. I guess that you can do this with pure SQL.

Comment: SQL JOINs anyone...? We do not have enough information here to optimise anything in detail. Maybe you actually *need* to iterate all those arrays. Maybe you don't. We don't know.

Comment: Besides looking for a match between A and B, which can probably be handled by rewriting your SQL queries; what do you actually do if a match is or isn't found?

Comment: If a match is found I run a case switch which is simple. Therefor I cannot use SQL for everything. 

And due to the processing of these array elements I need to iterate. What I was thinking is maybe there is a php library that speed up the iterations and handling of arrays.

Comment: And what do you do if no match is found? An SQL query may be able to eliminate a large number of those iterations; but there is no "magic bullet" make my iterating faster library for PHP.... though you might consider using [SPLFixedArray](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) rather than standard PHP arrays.... at the very least, it will reduce your memory usage

Comment: -1 For inconstructive question. In order to get a valuable response you should show your current code, and what it exactly should do ("If no match is found I run a case switch which is simple" isn't exactly helpfull).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different answers. My guess is that the first one is the right one, the
easy one and sufficient, but it's very hard to be sure.

## Possible Answer 1: Use SQL

As the comments indicate it sounds awfully lot like a join. In addition your post seem
to indicate that you only take an action when a match is found and that not every element
in A have a match. This mean your SQL statement should only return the matching rows, not
all of them. It doesn't matter that you can't do everything i SQL, if you can let it 
organise your data for you.

## Possible Answer 2: Sort the arrays

Maybe you can sort the arrays (again, preferably let your database do this). Possibly you
can sort B so that search for a match is quicker. Or put the search value in the key of the
array so that searching is very quick. Or if you are lucky you might be able to sort both
arrays in a way that makes all A's and B's in the same order. i.e. for any A you pick you
know that the right B either do not exist or exist later in the B array.

## Possible Answer 3: Explain more about the problem

You have only given us your current algorithm, not what you are actually trying to do. Most
likely iterating over everything is not the best idea, but no one can say unless they know
more about your data and what you want to do in the end.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your data, of course....

some general aspects:

- this really sounds like a use case for the database queries, not the php script. Looking for matches in datasets is what databases are good at, no tricks will make php scripts play even in the same league
- if you really have to use the php scripting functions try to

  - not to hit your allowed memory limits. your php server will just exit with an error, but if your sql site result set becomes too big your sql server may begin to write temp data to the hd, which will slow down the whole execution time -> if possible, fetch and process the data in chunks (offset, limit)
  - if you match whole words, build your matching array in such a way, that the search criterion is a key, not a value, so that you can use `isset($potentialMatches[$searchTerm])`, which is way faster than `in_array($searchTerm, $potentialMatches)` for larger arrays. Mockup:

    while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    $potentialMatches[$row['search_column']] = $row;
    }

---

but it can't be stressed enough: the usual course to handle this would be:

1. do the matching DB-side
2. process the matches in your script
3. if necessary: do a new query for non-matches
4. if 3., process those results in your script